# Checking if all values in binary tree are lower than all values in an other binary tree

Tags: java, data-structures

I have a function - lessThanTree(BinNode t1, int value) that returns  true if value is lower than all values in t1.

now I have an assignment to use this function and write another function that receives two binary trees(t1,t2) and returns true if all values in t1 are lower than all values in t2.

I wrote this recursive code:

```
public static boolean treeLessThanTree(BinNode<Integer> t1, BinNode<Integer> t2) {
        if (t1 == null)
            return true;
        return lessThanTree(t2, t1.getValue()) && treeLessThanTree(t1.getLeft(), t2)
                && treeLessThanTree(t1.getRight(), t2);
    }
```

Will this work?

Comment: Did you try running this?

Comment: Looks it would work.

Comment: @user7 I have some troubles creating two binary trees.. In school we usually write the code and the teacher checks it for us..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work, but if the two trees are binary search trees, it unnecessarily calls `lessThanTree(t2, t1.getValue())` and `treeLessThanTree(t1.getLeft(), t2)`.

It's enough to return `treeLessThanTree(t1.getRight(), t2)` (as long as `t1.getRight()` is not null), since the largest element of `t1` is always located in the right sub-tree (or in the root, if the root has no right sub-tree).

Therefore, a more efficient solution would be:

```
public static boolean treeLessThanTree(BinNode<Integer> t1, BinNode<Integer> t2) 
{
    if (t1 == null)
        return true;
    else if (t1.getRight() != null)
        return treeLessThanTree(t1.getRight(), t2);
    else 
        return lessThanTree(t2, t1.getValue());
}
```

Comment: The OP did not say it is a BST

Comment: If that is the case we can traverse to the right most node and check only that.

Comment: Toda! I forgot that the largest elements are always in the right sub-tree

Comment: @user7 oops, for some reason I thought it was a binary search tree.

Comment: @DAVIDBALAS1 that's only correct if the trees are binary search trees, which you didn't mention in your question. If they are general binary trees, my answers is incorrect. Please let me know.

Comment: Apparently, it seems it is what the OP wants :). +1

Answer (score 1):

public class BinaryTree {
    private Node root;

```
private class Node{
    private Node left;
    private Node right;
    private Integer data;
    public Node(Integer data){
        this.left = null;
        this.right = null;
        this.data = data;
    }
}

public BinaryTree(){
    root = null;
}

public void buildTree(Node node,Integer data){
    if(root == null){
        root = new Node(data);
    }else{
        if(data < node.data){
            if(node.left == null){
                node.left = new Node(data);
            }else{
                buildTree(node.left,data);
            }
        }else{
            if(node.right == null){
                node.right = new Node(data);
            }else{
                buildTree(node.right,data);
            }
        }
    }
}


public void preOrder(Node node){  
    if(node != null){  
        System.out.println(node.data);  
        preOrder(node.left);  
        preOrder(node.right);  
    }  
}  


public void inOrder(Node node){  
    if(node != null){  
        inOrder(node.left);  
        System.out.println(node.data);  
        inOrder(node.right);  
    }  
}  


public void postOrder(Node node){  
    if(node != null){  
        postOrder(node.left);  
        postOrder(node.right);  
        System.out.println(node.data);  
    }  
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

To determine if all of the items in t1 are smaller than all the nodes in t2, all you have to do is make sure that the *largest* item in t1 is smaller than the *smallest* item in t2.

If the trees are binary search trees, then finding the smallest item is a simple matter of traversing from the root to the lowest, left-most item. And you get the largest by traversing from the root to the lowest, right-most item.

If they're not binary search trees, then you have to traverse the entire tree to find the smallest and largest items.

If the trees are balanced binary search trees, then complexity is O(log(t1.length) + log(t2.length)) Otherwise, worst case is O(t1.length + t2.length).